# JQuery set top and left half of elements width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My project's fiddle - http://jsbin.com/ipEmIBAfa/3/edit

What I'm trying to do is simple. I grab my elements height, and divide that by 2, and set that as my elements margin-top and margin-left css properties.

This is my code, but it's not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$('#elementname').css({ position : "absolute" });
$('#elementname').css({ top : "50%" });
$('#elementname').css({ left : "50%" });
$('#elementname').css({ marginTop : ("-" + parseInt($('#elm-height').val()) / 2) + "px" });
$('#elementname').css({ marginLeft : ("-" + parseInt($('#elm-width').val()) / 2) + "px" });
```

Comment: Any console errors? And why are you not stacking your `.css()` in one function?

Comment: Nope. Normally I do have it all in one function. I will be combining it in one later, but haven't got around to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group that addition process with `parenthesis`.

Edit:

you are `concatenating "-"`, instead try to multiply that value by `-1`,

Try,

```
$('#elementname').css({ position : "absolute" });
$('#elementname').css({ top : "50%" });
$('#elementname').css({ left : "50%" });
$('#elementname').css({ marginTop : ((-1 * parseInt($('#elm-height').val())) / 2) + "px" });
$('#elementname').css({ marginLeft : ((-1 * parseInt($('#elm-width').val())) / 2) + "px" });
```

Comment: Fixed it with..
    $('#elementname').css({ marginTop : "-" + (parseInt($('#elm-height').val()) / 2) + "px" });
    $('#elementname').css({ marginLeft : "-" + (parseInt($('#elm-width').val()) / 2) + "px" });